# continuity of a function without a specified point

Tags: calculus

I know how to check continuity of a function at a given point. I also know that a function is said to be continuous if it is continuous at every point in its domain. When I am asked if a function is continuous, for example $f(x,y)=\frac{2}{5x^3y}$, do I first find the domain and see if there are any points of discontinuities in the domain? In this case, domain of $f(x,y)=\{(x,y)\in  \mathbb{R}^2:x\ne 0 \text{ or } y \ne 0\}$. Will I be correct to say that f(x,y) is continuous since the points of discontinuities are not in the domain of f(x,y)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say that "$f(x,y)$ is continuous since the points of discontinuities are not in the domain of $f(x,y)$" is not perfectly rigorous (since the function simply does not exist outside its domain, so you can't even say that there are discontinuities in that *nowhere*), but it captures the correct intuition.

You only care about what happens in the domain of the function; so, for example, if you have a function that is continuous somewhere and discontinuous elsewhere, and you remove from the domain all points of discontinuity, you are left with a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

no, there are no points of discontinuities at all here!

to be continuous or not, first the function has to be defined at a point!
(if not defined, you can't say it is continuous or discontinuous -- see the definition of continuity)

in this example, you can say that $f$ is continuous since it is a quotient of two continuous functions

Comment: given $f(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$, I think that even though f(x) is not defined at x=1, I can still say f(x) is not continuous at x=1. For this, I reffer you to Tomas calculs 11th edition page 127, read example 5 please.